# Differential equation, determinant = 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$$(x+2y+1)y' = 2x+4y+3$$

So i've tried to write it like:

$$y' = \frac{(2x+4y+3)}{x+2y+1}$$

and when i do the determinant i get that its $0$.

I've tried to write it then with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ like:
$$2\alpha + 4\beta +1 = 0$$
$$\alpha + 2\beta + 1 = 0$$

But i also end up with $0$ no mather what i try.
Im not sure what other way should I try.
Can you help me out?

Comment: What does *when i do the determinant* mean? And if the linear system is related to your DE, I would guess the first equation should be $2\alpha + 4\beta +3 = 0$

Comment: You have asked 4 other questions so far, to which you have not accepted any answer. People care about these things, so if you keep not accepting answers they will end up avoiding your questions. While not every answer may be satisfactory, and it mays sense not to accept them when they are so, I have seen some very good answers given to your previous questions, which raises the question: why haven't you accepted them?

Comment: @gammatester: I am not sure, but it seems that the OP uses the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ in that fraction to come up with the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, like a linear-fractional transformation. I do not understand why he does it, though, I know no theorem that goes like this.

Comment: The equations are *inconsistent*, no solution exists.

Comment: @Nikunj: ??? I beg your pardon?

Comment: @AlexM. I have accepted all the answers and all of them were helpful to me. I am new here and i still might not know how to do everything right, so i am sorry if i missed something.

Comment: @mirai: At the top left of every answer it is displayed the score of that answer, together with an up-arrow and a down-arrow. Next to them there is a check mark. You accept an answer by clicking that check mark (it turns green when you do this): the question is marked internally as answered, the answerer gets 15 points and you get 2.

Comment: @AlexM. I did it for all my questions now. I am sorry, i missed it.

Comment: @AlexM. I was thinking about a 'trick' I use to solve DE's of the kind (linear)/(linear)  (like the one in the question) it requires the substitution $x=x+\alpha,y=y+\beta$ where $(\alpha,\beta)$ is the solution of the numerator and denominator solved simultaneously.

Comment: @Nikunj: I see. I believe that this is what the OP was attempting, and this is why he was complaining that the determinant is $0$.

Comment: @Nikunj That makes sense. I would never thought of that, honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can cancel to
$$
y'=2+\frac1{x+2y+1}.
$$
You could also substitute $u=x+2y$ to find
$$
u'=1+2y'=5+\frac2{u+1}
$$

Comment: Thanks so much! That was really helpful. I found it a bit weird, but I did it!

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the denominator you introduced, define $$x+2y+1=z\implies y=\frac{1}{2} (z-x-1)\implies y'=\frac{1}{2} \left(z'-1\right)$$ Replace in the original equation $$(x+2y+1)y' = 2x+4y+3$$ and you will find a nice separable equation.